# Matrix imported by getSplits (quantmod) is shaped in different way based on symbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to import stock data (split), and I have a problem.
There is no issue if all symbols contain split. When one of them does not have split, however, the matrix are shaped in different way and wrong.

Here are codes that I use:

```
library(quantmod)

Tick <- c("AA","ARGO")

split_test <- Reduce(merge, lapply(Tick, function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    getSplits(x, from= "2016-01-04", to="2017-03-09", src="yahoo")
  }, error = function(e) {}
  )
}))
```

and the outcome is fine:

```
               AA.spl         ARGO.spl
2016-05-27     N/A            0.9091
2016-10-06     3.000            N/A
2016-11-01     0.801            N/A
```

The problem is that if Tick includes "A" which does not have split , the outcome is quite different and wrong:

```
Tick <- c("A","AA","ARGO")

     x     AA.spl         ARGO.spl
1    N/A    3.000         0.9091
2    N/A    0.801         0.9091
```

Dates are not shown up anymore, and the value is also wrong(same number repeats).
How do I get outcome like first one even though a stock has no split? If it is possible I want "A" is just shown up as N/As like:

```
             A.spl       AA.spl         ARGO.spl
2016-05-27   N/A          N/A            0.9091
2016-10-06   N/A         3.000            N/A
2016-11-01   N/A         0.801            N/A
```

## getDividends

```
Tick <- c("A","AA","AADR","AAN","AAP","AAT")

Test <-
  lapply(Tick,
         function(x) {
           try(getDividends(x, from= "2016-01-04", to="2016-03-15", src="yahoo"),
               silent = TRUE)
         })
names(Test) <- Tick

# convert NA to xts object with date < 1900
Test <-
  lapply(Test,
         function(x) {
           if (identical(x, NA)) xts(NA, .Date(-4e4)) else x
         })

# merge and remove pre-1900 date
Test <- Reduce(merge, Test)["1900/"]
```

Comment: I don't get the same output as shown. I get column name as `x..i..` with all `NA`'s and the value do not repeat for me for other columns.

Comment: Really? I just tired again with "Tick <- c("A","AA","ARGO")" and got same result as I posted above. Could you try once more?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't like this behavior. It would make more sense to me to have a 'zero-length' xts object. That's not currently possible and has been discussed before, but I haven't had time to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSplits()` just returns `NA` for "A", not an xts object. And "A" is first in your `Tick` vector, so the `merge()` method for xts objects isn't being called (because of how S3 method dispatch works).

You could use `cbind()` instead of `merge()` because method dispatch for `cbind()` works different. But I wouldn't suggest that solution, because you're not likely to remember that subtle difference between the two functions.

Instead, I would pre-process your list of splits before merging.

```
split_test <-
  lapply(Tick,
         function(x) {
           try(getSplits(x, from= "2016-01-04", to="2017-03-09", src="yahoo"),
               silent = TRUE)
         })
names(split_test) <- Tick

# convert NA to xts object with date < 1900
split_test <-
  lapply(split_test,
         function(x) {
           if (identical(x, NA)) xts(NA, .Date(-4e4)) else x
         })

# merge and remove pre-1900 date
split_test <- Reduce(merge, split_test)["1900/"]
# set names
names(split_test) <- Tick

split_test
##               AA  A      ARGO
## 2016-05-27    NA NA 0.9090909
## 2016-10-06 3.000 NA        NA
## 2016-11-01 0.801 NA        NA
```

The code checks for list elements that are only `NA`, and replaces the `NA` with an xts object that has a date index before 1900. That date will be easy to identify in the output.

Then we merge all the list elements together using `Reduce()`, like you did. And we set the names to your `Tick` vector, so the column that didn't have any data has the correct ticker name.

---

Update for `getDividends()`, since it returns a zero-width xts object when there are no dividends, not NA like `getSplits()` does. We can add another check to the function that adjusts the xts objects with NA.

Let's move this to a function, since you need it in more than one place. We can add another condition to the `if` statement.

```
fill_missing <-
function(x)
{
    y <- x
    if (identical(x, NA) || length(x) < 1) {
        y <- xts(NA, .Date(-4e4))
    }
    y
}
```

Now use this function in your `lapply()` call and do the same `Reduce()` call. Then you can set names again, if you need to.

```
Test <- lapply(Test, fill_missing)
out <- Reduce(merge, Test)["1900/"]
out <- out[,Tick]
```

Comment: Wow! You saved me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to get Dividend by using the codes you wrote. I thought it should be same as getSplits, but stocks that do not have dividend are not shown up when I run  Test <- Reduce(merge, Test)["1900/"]   Could you see the codes that I posted above?

Comment: Sorry for my slow response. I don't check SO that often. See my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm struggling using getDividends and getSplits. As you know if some of symbols are invalid, an error occurs; "Handle is already in use elsewhere".   I read your post from gitHub "getSymbols.yahoo warnings #307". You said we should make it skip an invalid symbol and succeed getting the next valid one. I'm so sorry but I have no idea how to do this.  Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: @DongchulPark this should be fixed in quantmod version 0.4.18. Please make sure you're using that version. Reply to issue #307 if you're still having issues. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Could you help with this - https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65720/asset-pricing-and-negative-prices  @JoshuaUlrich